# Python nmap module error (decreasing to 2.0\nRTTVAR has grown to over 2.3 seconds)

Tags: python, nmap

Well, this is just all kinds of weird to me. I've been working on this script to automate some nmap scans, and dump them into a database to hopefully do comparisons and find out which ports are open that might not have been open during the last scan. The script is below, and it worked great for the first test run, but when I changed the hostlist variable to scan a different subnet, it quit working. The scan took WAAAY longer than normal, and when it finally errored out it just printed two or three screens worth of

```
"(decreasing to 2.0\nRTTVAR has grown to over 2.3 seconds)"
```

It would alternate between 2.0 and 2.3 seconds, but that's pretty much the spam I got dumped to stdout. The first time I ran the script and it worked I didn't have the day checker in there, but when I commented those out and tried to run it again the way it was the first time it worked, with the new subnet as the only difference, it was still borked. Any thoughts on what's going on? Script is below. Don't mind that I don't actually use the results variable, it's a young script and I'm still learning the nmap module ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# automated nmap scanning script

import nmap
import MySQLdb
#import datetime

# initialize port scanner and hosts to be scanned

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

#if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 2:
hostlist = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24'

# open database connection and prepare a cursor

db = MySQLdb.connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX","XXXX")

cursor = db.cursor()

# scan

results = nm.scan(hosts=hostlist, arguments='-PN')

for item in nm.all_hosts():
#       print('Host: %s (%s)') % (item, nm[item]['hostname'])
        if 'tcp' in nm[item]:
                for port in nm[item]['tcp'].keys():
#                       print("\t %s") % (port)
                        sql = "INSERT INTO scanresults (ipaddress, port) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (item, port)
                        try:
                                cursor.execute(sql)
                                db.commit()
                        except:
                                print "There was an error!"
                                db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Comment: Further testing seems to indicate this is a problem with nmap and/or the target subnet, not my script. Google doesn't turn up any useful information on what could be causing it, however, and this is a subnet I've run nmap on before without any issue. Bizarre. I'll have to do some more scan testing and get with our network guys, see if they have any ideas.

Comment: For anyone who reads this, more research shows that it's apparently some kind of arp table overflow problem. The fix was to enter these variables into the appropriate config file `net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 4096
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 2048
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 1024
` Which fixed a straight nmap scan, however... doing the scan from python still appears to be broken. It kind of hangs, and never finishes or errors out, the cursor just hangs, and I never get back to my python prompt